# activex checkbox loop- selects linked cell offset then copies row

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, activex

I have about 50 checkboxes that are all linked to the cell that they are positioned on(eg checkbox in A2 is linked to cell A2). I have the loop working to a degree.
The issue i am having is making the linked cell selected and the offset by 1 cell then copy the row leaving out the linked cell.
then pastes to different worksheet to the next blank row.

```
Sub CheckboxLoop()
Dim objx As OLEObject
Dim lastrow As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop through Checkboxes
With ActiveSheet
    For Each objx In .OLEObjects
        If TypeName(objx.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            If objx.Object.Value = True Then
                If objx.Object.LinkedCell = True Then   'runtime error 438 object doesn't support this property or method
                    objx.Object.LinkedCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                    Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1), Cells(Selection.Row, 3)).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Worksheet("Data").Select
                    Worksheet("Data").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
                    Selection.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False

                End If

            ElseIf objx.Object.Value = False Then


            ElseIf IsNull(objx.Object.Value) Then


            End If
        End If
    Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

When i step through the macro is all fine until i get to the 3rd if and i receive the runtime error 438 object doesn't support this property or method

Any help would be awesome thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LinkedCell` property is of `String` type and stores/retrieves the address of the cell linked to the combobox

So you want to use

```
         If objx.LinkedCell <>"" Then 
             .Range(objx.LinkedCell).Offset(0, 1).Select
             '... rest of your code

         End If
```

Comment: thanks, but it still has the runtime error with this line If objx.Object.LinkedCell <>"" Then

Comment: Thanks that worked ... once lol. but anyway. now its Run-Time error 1004 with  Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select

Comment: If I fullfilled your original question please mark my answer as accepted. Thank you. As for your new issue start a new question